# How to check if a file exists in python?

Tags: python, windows, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pythonic way to check if a file exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259382/pythonic-way-to-check-if-a-file-exists)

How to check if a file exists in python?

Scripting in Windows

Comment: @vpit3833: I would say "more than possibly". ;-)

Comment: Note that selected answer is incorrect - question is about file, selected asnwer will respond "yes" also for directories

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is very easy using the [`os`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) module.

```
from os.path import exists
print exists("C:\somefile.txt")
```

Comment: What if the file is in an 'extended' path? Eg "\\?\C:\<very long path>"

Comment: @bgura why would it make a difference?

Comment: @Benj. I actually ran into issue with long paths on windows a while back and python kept saying the path does not exist. On Windows, you need to use a special syntax to access "long" paths See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21194605/1161132. I cannot recall offhand if python supports the syntax or if it will normalize long path's via the conventional format (i.e. C:\path\...)

Comment: @bgura That's interesting! I'm afraid I cannot answer your question though...

Comment: This is an incorrect answer - question is about file, this will answer yes also for directories

Answer (score 5):

Check the manual, this is a really easy question:

http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists

> ```
> os.path.exists(path)
> ```
>
> Return True if path refers to an existing path. Returns False for broken symbolic links. On some platforms, this function may return False if permission is not granted to execute os.stat() on the requested file, even if the path physically exists.

Comment: This is an incorrect answer - question is about file, this will answer yes also for directories

Answer (score 4):

http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists

or if you want to also ensure that said path is actually a file (as opposed to a directory, link, etc):

http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile

Comment: Could you please summarise those links?