# How can I delete a "infinite" folder?

Tags: windows, cmd, directory, rmdir, delete-directory

I was doing a program in Java and I've created, recursively, a folder that has a folder in, and so on.

I've tried to delete it but Window says it can't be deleted because is too big.

How can I delete it? Already tried rmdir /s /q and nothing.

Need Help.

Comment: Is it really infinite? or is it just really deep? the only possible way I think it could be infinite would be if it was using links and not folders

Comment: Robocopy will work, as per [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/423821/96662).

Answer (score 2):

`\\?\` turns off file name checks.

```
rmdir /s /q "\\?\c:\somefolder\somefile.ext"
```

For explanation, see *[What does \?\ mean when prepended to a file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194530/what-does-mean-when-prepended-to-a-file-path)*, which points to *[Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)* (MSDN).

Answer (score 1):

You could boot from an Ubuntu Live CD/DVD and delete the folder.  The command would be:

```
rm -rf myBigFolder
```

Comment: If you have git installed with Unix commands, then you can use Unix-like commands on Windows. Meaning you can delete the "infinite" folder using the same command, i.e. `rm -rf myBigFolder`