# How do I remove an Error.error file being created and cannot be deleted?

Tags: file

How do I delete/remove the "Error.error" file when the system says it is not there but it is?

The Error.error file was created somehow and I do not know why or how. However, the issue is the system has created this 0 byte file called "Error.error" and it cannot be deleted, even if I try a "permanent" delete command. It also will not allow me to delete any of the folder directory hierarchy in which is resides. When I do try create it, rename it, or create a physical file with the same name and extension, or try to delete this file directly or indirectly I receive the following error message:

"Could not find this item: This is no longer located in C:\maps\test. Verify the items location and try again." Then it list "Error.error" and its information. However, it is there visually.

Any thoughts or suggestions on how to remove or correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a very similar issue not too long ago where I had a file that was created by another program and whenever I tried to access or delete it, windows would give an error message like "...This is no longer located in...".

If you're having the same problem I was, here's how I got rid of the file.  Start a command prompt.  In the command prompt, enter a command like `del "\\?\<full path to file>"`.  So if your file name is "Error.error" and it is located in the folder "C:\maps\test", the command you would enter is

```
del "\\?\C:\maps\test\Error.error"
```

You can delete a folder that windows won't let you access in a similar way by changing the command from "del" to "rd /S".

If you don't know how to start a command prompt, simply click the start button and type "command".  The start menu should offer an option named something like "Command Prompt - Desktop app".  That's what you need to start.

I found a good explanation of what the "\\?\" means [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194530/what-does-mean-when-prepended-to-a-file-path).

Comment: Thanks New Pagodi! When I used the "rd /S" command it allowed me to to delete the directory and the file. When I tried to delete the file directly through the command prompt it would not work.