# Delete stubborn folder with points in name

Tags: command-prompt, prompt, delete-directory

I'm trying to delete a folder with weird name: "T.E.E.M." 
Windows doesn't recognize this kind of name and even tell me the folder can't be found (it was created via NodeJs, but i don't know why windows allowed it).

[image]

I tried to delete it normally and it says that the folder can't be found because it doesn't exist.

[image]

I tried in prompt too, using the 2 commands `del "T.E.E.M."` inside the right folder and `Rmdir /S "T.E.E.M."` but they both don't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: I am not very good in Italian, but I do have a few suggestions you could try. Try the command prompt in Administrator mode. Try to reboot your system, maybe a file is locked. And have you tried to type "del t<TAB>"? By entering the <TAB>-key, the file system auto completes the filename. Maybe there is some non-visual character in the filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows cannot handle files/folders ending on a period-symbol ('.'). That's what I discovered when I tried to create the "T.E.E.M."-folder myself. I ended up with a "T.E.E.M"-folder (without the last period).
So this might do the trick for you:

```
del "\\?\<full path to file>"
```

but since this is a directory, maybe

```
rmdir /s "\\?\<full path to file>"
```

works better.

By entering \\?\ string parsing is [disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40639191/1770778).

Original answer found [here](https://superuser.com/a/742379/303364).

Comment: It didn't work using rmdir, it says the folder is not empty (I actually don't know how, i cannot access it in any way). 
And using del, it says that it's impossible to find that directory

Comment: Have you tried `rmdir /s "\\?\<full path to file>"`?

Comment: With the /s worked just fine, thank you very much! I will mark your answer, thanks! Update it if you can :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a stubborn folder. I tried adjusting the security settings , shift-delete and all of the more standard attempts, I made sure the folder was empty and made sure all files were viewable. In desperation I performed the follwing steps:

1. Command prompt "cmd"
2. Once the command prompt came up I typed in "regedit"
3. Performed search in the registry and poof out popped a listing of the folder with a mystery file shown in the path of the stubborn folder.
4. I deleted the entry (warnings that it  is dangerous to fool with the registry.)
5. Rebooted my computer and looked for the now deleted folder and IT WAS GONE.