# Acumatica Extension Library - Cannot Load Project

Tags: c#, acumatica

I am new to Acumatica and attempt to go through the T200 Course (Maintenance Forms). I created a new Extension Library and moved my code over. However, I encountered an issue when opening the solution. In VS, the solution consists of two projects: what seems to be the Extension Library itself (e.g. containing my Graph and DAC classes) and another which looks to be a reference to the Acumatica tenant/website. The first one (Extension Library) loads and builds fine. However, the other (the website?) fails to load. The output is as follows:

```
C:\Program Files\Acumatica ERP\MHC : error  : Configuring IIS Express failed with the following error:

Filename: \\?\Z:\acu_test\PhoneRepairDemo_Code\.vs\PhoneRepairDemo_Code\config\applicationhost.config
Error: Cannot read configuration file
```

In this case, the path begining at `C:` is the website project that is failing to load; the path beginning with `Z:` is the Extension Library. I noticed that, for some reason, `\\?\` is being prepended to the Extension Library path. That is, `Z:\acu_test\PhoneRepairDemo_Code\.vs\PhoneRepairDemo_Code\config\applicationhost.config` actually does point to a valid file, but `\\?\Z:\acu_test\PhoneRepairDemo_Code\.vs\PhoneRepairDemo_Code\config\applicationhost.config` obviously does not. I am not quite sure where VS is "grabbing" this path from. I had assumed it was through one of the project/app config files, but could find no such setting in either Project. Any advice on how to fix?

Thanks!

Comment: \\?\... means this is an extended length path: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21194605. Is Z: a local or a mapped network drive? If it is a network drive, can you try running off your boot disk to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: Thanks for the information. Running it off the boot drive (C: here) fixed it. For my particular case, this is workable but not ideal. Is there any way place an Extension Lib on a mapped drive? Regardless, thanks much!