Invalid path to Web.config in IIS when accessing Application Settings
I have a website setup in IIS 7 and when I try to access the Application Settings I get the following error.

The path to the web.config is correct but it is adding \?\ to the beginning of the path.  When I access the site I get a 500 error with the same error.

Very related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21194530/319403

That file path is actually valid, but you just hit a typical 500.19 issue where a certain out-of-band IIS module was missing. Review that web.config file and find it out.

Try using FRT to view details about the 500 error, which will generate a detailed log file to help you identify the problem.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis
