# Safely create a file if and only if it does not exist with Python

Tags: python

I wish to write to a file based on whether that file already exists or not, only writing if it doesn't already exist (in practice, I wish to keep trying files until I find one that doesn't exist).

The following code shows a way in which a potentially attacker could insert a symlink, as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/85237/709852) in between a test for the file and the file being written. If the code is run with high enough permissions, this could overwrite an arbitrary file.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

```
import os
import errno

file_to_be_attacked = 'important_file'

with open(file_to_be_attacked, 'w') as f:
    f.write('Some important content!\n')

test_file = 'testfile'

try:
    with open(test_file) as f: pass
except IOError, e:

    # Symlink created here
    os.symlink(file_to_be_attacked, test_file)

    if e.errno != errno.ENOENT:
        raise
    else:
        with open(test_file, 'w') as f:
            f.write('Hello, kthxbye!\n')
```

Comment: Check atomic writing with Python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333872/atomic-writing-to-file-with-python

Comment: @Mikko That doesn’t help here.

Comment: Ah ok. I understood what's the matter... you write ONLY if the file exist?

Comment: Could you write the file in a temporary location, then do a copy command without allowing overwrite?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

**Edit**: See also [Dave Jones' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18474773/220155): from Python 3.3, you can use the `x` flag to `open()` to provide this function.

**Original answer below**

Yes, but not using Python's standard `open()` call. You'll need to use [`os.open()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.open) instead, which allows you to specify flags to the underlying C code.

In particular, you want to use `O_CREAT | O_EXCL`. From the man page for `open(2)` under `O_EXCL` on my Unix system:

> Ensure  that  this  call  creates the file: if this flag is specified in conjunction with `O_CREAT`, and pathname already exists, then `open()` will fail.  The behavior of `O_EXCL` is undefined if `O_CREAT` is not specified.
>
> When these two flags are specified, symbolic links are not followed: if pathname is a symbolic link, then `open()` fails  regardless of where the symbolic link points to.
>
> `O_EXCL`  is only supported on NFS when using NFSv3 or later on kernel 2.6 or later.  In environments where NFS `O_EXCL` support is not provided, programs that rely on it for performing locking tasks will contain a race condition.

So it's not perfect, but AFAIK it's the closest you can get to avoiding this race condition.

Edit: the other rules of using `os.open()` instead of `open()` still apply. In particular, if you want use the returned file descriptor for reading or writing, you'll need one of the `O_RDONLY`, `O_WRONLY` or `O_RDWR` flags as well.

All the `O_*` flags are in Python's `os` module, so you'll need to `import os` and use `os.O_CREAT` etc.

#### Example:

```
import os
import errno

flags = os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL | os.O_WRONLY

try:
    file_handle = os.open('filename', flags)
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno == errno.EEXIST:  # Failed as the file already exists.
        pass
    else:  # Something unexpected went wrong so reraise the exception.
        raise
else:  # No exception, so the file must have been created successfully.
    with os.fdopen(file_handle, 'w') as file_obj:
        # Using `os.fdopen` converts the handle to an object that acts like a
        # regular Python file object, and the `with` context manager means the
        # file will be automatically closed when we're done with it.
        file_obj.write("Look, ma, I'm writing to a new file!")
```

Comment: +1 for the obviously correct answer.  I'm personally curious to know how many people actually have issues with the NFS caveat—I (perhaps recklessly) dismiss it as an obsolete environment my code should never be run on.

Comment: @zigg: NFSv3 is from 1995, so it seems fair to regard older versions as obsolete.

Comment: I'd be more worried about the kernel version, personally. If you're running anything even vaguely resembling an up-to-date system, you should have no issue, but RHEL 3 (still in extended support phase) is running a 2.4 kernel, for example. Also, I've not investigated if they provide atomic writes on Windows on FAT or NTFS, which is a potentially major limitation.

Comment: (Although the OP talks about `os.symlink()`, which is Unix-only, so Windows is presumably not so much of an issue for them.)

Comment: @me_and The python page on [open flag constants](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#open-constants) suggests that this works fine with Windows. I'll be trying it shortly!

Comment: True, but I've not seen anywhere (including [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53xa7z70(v=VS.71).aspx)) that explicitly says these flags give *atomic* file creation. Possibly I'm being overly paranoid, but I'd want to see that "atomic" keyword before trusting this for anything that's security-critical.

Comment: @me_and could you add an example please?

Comment: @me_and could you also do this:    f=open('file.txt.','a')    f.close() f=open('file.txt','r+')    so python creates a file only if it doesnt exist, then closes and opens the [old or brand new] file ...?

Comment: @pinhead Welcome to Stack Overflow! You're better asking questions in new questions, because they're more visible and you're not limited by comment formatting or character limits. In any case, your code doesn't solve the problem, where we explicitly want to open the file if _and only if_ it doesn't already exist.

Comment: This solution works just for a file, i.e. it does not work if you use a full path and the parent directory does not exist.

Comment: @zigg NFS is widely used in High Performance Computing environments (HPC), where Python is a popular choice. Although I have never seen anything else than NFSv3. You should expect that every line of code you send to PyPi will be run on NFSv3 at some point.

Answer (score 89):

For reference, Python 3.3 implements a new `'x'` mode in the [`open()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function to cover this use-case (create only, fail if file exists). Note that the `'x'` mode is specified on its own. Using `'wx'` results in a `ValueError` as the `'w'` is redundant (the only thing you can do if the call succeeds is write to the file anyway; it can't have existed if the call succeeds):

```
>>> f1 = open('new_binary_file', 'xb')
>>> f2 = open('new_text_file', 'x')
```

For Python 3.2 and below (including Python 2.x) please refer to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10979569/1459019).

Comment: Good suggestion. Unfortunately this appears to be POSIX-only (doesn't work on Windows): `Python 3.2 (r32:88445, Feb 20 2011, 21:30:00)` `[MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`
`>>> open("c:/temp/foo.csv","wx")` `ValueError: invalid mode: 'wx'`

Comment: You're using python 3.2; the 'x' mode is in 3.3 and above but it is cross platform. Incidentally, you only use 'x' instead of 'wx' - the write mode is redundant as the only thing you could do with the file is write to it anyway

Comment: How are 'w' and 'x' duplicates? It's perfectly reasonable to open an existing file for writing (which overwrites it).

Comment: It is reasonable to open an existing file for writing, but the entire point of the 'x' mode is to open the file *if and only if it doesn't exist already*, failing with an error when the file does exist. This is why it is redundant with the 'w' flag; if it succeeds the file is guaranteed to be empty (and hence there's very little point reading from it :).

Answer (score -2):

This code will easily create a *file* if one does not exists.

```
import os
if not os.path.exists('file'):
    open('file', 'w').close()
```

Comment: Yes it will. The important point about the question was the safety aspect. The problem is that between identifying the presence of the file and using it or creating it, something might change that results in a bad outcome (as in the original question).

Comment: That's true. It's called TOCTOU!

Comment: If another process creates and writes to the file after the `if` statement, this code will blank out the file.