# Safely pickle a file if and only if it does not exist - avoiding a race condition

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle, race-condition

In parallel, I'm saving a lot of csv's without column names so I can use `cat` to quickly bring them together in unix without bringing them together. These csv's have 1000+ columns, so I'd like to save a single copy of the column headers for when I re-aggregate them, but because I am creating these files in parallel, I'd like only the first job to pickle the pandas index object.

Normally, to avoid the race condition when writing a file, I'd use `os.open()` As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978869/safely-create-a-file-if-and-only-if-it-does-not-exist-with-python). However, I tried to combine that when pickling:

```
cPickle.dump( df.columns, os.open( "/dir/my_columns.pkl", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREAT|os.O_EXCL ),-1 )
```

But the second argument to `pickle.dump` needs an argument with a write attribute, but the object returned by `os.open()` does not have an attribute. Is there an alternative that would allow me to safely save this object if multiple threads are racing to create it?

Comment: To avoid race conditions, lock the file for writing, release the lock when done. And the don't open files like that, especially in a case where you're dealing with multiple threads trying to open the same file. Use the `with` statement.

Comment: I think your question is how to create a file object from a file descriptor. Or how to pass flags to the `open` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new file using `os.open`, close it `os.close` and then reopen it with `open`:

```
import os
import cPickle

fileName = "/dir/my_columns.pkl"
try:
    # Ensure that only one thread continues beyond this point
    os.close(os.open( fileName, os.O_CREAT|os.O_EXCL ))
except OSError:
    raise RuntimeError(fileName + " could not be created.")

with open(fileName, 'w') as f:
    cPickle.dump( df.columns, f, -1 )
```