# Python create file safely

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want create file safely in python2.7

```
import os
import sys
logname = "logfile"
f = open(logname, 'w')
sys.stdout = f
print "file created with file name {}".format(logname)
f.close()
```

Above script will overwrite if file is exist. I dont want to recreate it.

Say if file name "logfile" already exist, try to create with "logfile1" name.

Comment: Can't you just check if the file exists before trying to create it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safely create a file if and only if it does not exist with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978869/safely-create-a-file-if-and-only-if-it-does-not-exist-with-python)

Comment: You could open in `a` mode for appending to an existing file or create if not exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`os.path.isfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) to check if the file already exists

```
if os.path.isfile(logname):
    logname = increment(logname) # increment the filename
f = open(logname, 'w')
sys.stdout = f
print "file created with file name {}".format(logname)
f.close()
```

Depending on your naming conventions, there are multiple ways you could implement your `increment` function