# Check if a file already exists in a particular folder

Tags: python, file, flask, werkzeug, os.path

I want, before uploading a file in image folder, to check if the file in the folder already exists or not. If the file already exists it should show a message.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from werkzeug import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/path/to/the/uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'GIF'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
import os, os.path


APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
UPLOAD_FOLD = '/python/image/'
UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, UPLOAD_FOLD)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER



@app.route('/upload')
def load_file():
return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route('/uploader', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
if request.method == 'POST':
  f = request.files['file']   
  f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],secure_filename(f.filename)))
  return 'file uploaded successfully'

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: Probably want to take a look at [os.path.isfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) or [os.path.exists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists).

Comment: Please have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978869/safely-create-a-file-if-and-only-if-it-does-not-exist-with-python

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether a `path` exists or not by using `os.path.exists` method, it returns `True` if the path passed as a parameter exists and returns `False` if it doesn't.

For instance: If you want to check if there is any file named `hello.c` in the current working directory, then you can use the following code:

```
from os import path
path.exists('hello.c') # This will return True if hello.c exists and will return False if it doesn't
```

Or You can use the absolute path too

For instance: If you want to check if there is any folder named `Users` in your C drive then you can use the following code:

```
from os import path
path.exists('C:\Users') # This will return True if Users exists in C drive and will return False if it doesn't
```