# Python - create directories that don't exist from list

Tags: python

I have a directory with the following subdirs:

folder_001 to folder_100

However, I need to test as some directories may be missing. Is the following the best way to accomplish this. Seems a bit long winded.

```
>>> l = []
>>> for i in l:
...  for f in os.listdir('.'):
...   if not os.path.exists(i):
...    os.mkdir(i)
...
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259382/pythonic-way-to-check-if-a-file-exists

Comment: I would just create every folder and ignore the error if it exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for i in xrange(1,101):
   name = 'folder_%03d' % (i)
   if not os.path.exists(name): 
      os.mkdir(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import shutil

for item in os.listdir('.'):
    if not os.path.exists(item):
        os.makedirs(item)
    else:
        shutil.rmtree(item)           #removes a tree with all subdirs!
        os.makedirs(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

more generic:

```
l = []
for f in os.listdir('.'):
    if f in l: l.remove(f)
for f in l:
    os.mkdir(f)
```

or:

```
l = []
dirs = os.listdir('.')
for f in l:
    if not f in dirs: os.mkdir(f)
```