# How to check text file exists and is not empty in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, filepath

I wrote a script to read text file in python.

Here is the code.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='script')    
parser.add_argument('-in', required=True, help='input file',
type=argparse.FileType('r'))
parser.add_argument('-out', required=True, help='outputfile',
type=argparse.FileType('w'))     
args = parser.parse_args()    

try:
    reader = csv.reader(args.in)
    for row in reader:
        print "good"
except csv.Error as e:
    sys.exit('file %s, line %d: %s' % (args.in, reader.line_num, e))

for ln in args.in:
    a, b = ln.rstrip().split(':')
```

I would like to check if the file exists and is not empty file but this code gives me an error.

I would also like to check if program can write to output file.

**Command:**

```
python script.py -in file1.txt -out file2.txt
```

**ERROR:**

```
good
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scritp.py", line 80, in <module>
    first_cluster = clusters[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259382/pythonic-way-to-check-if-a-file-exists

Comment: that code does not even parse, `in` is not a valid identifier (in `args.in`)

Comment: Where does `first_cluster = clusters[0]` appear in your code?

Comment: The script gives an error because the FOR loop gets failed. When it start reading file it failed to read file from args.in . how do i read file using argument parser?

Answer (score 62):

To check whether file is present and is not empty, you need to call the combination of [**`os.path.exists`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) and [**`os.path.getsize`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize) with the "and" condition. For example:

```
import os
my_path = "/path/to/file"

if os.path.exists(my_path) and os.path.getsize(my_path) > 0:
    # Non empty file exists
    # ... your code ...
else:
    # ... your code for else case ...
```

As an **alternative**, you may also use `try/except` with the [`os.path.getsize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize) *(without using `os.path.exists`)* because it raises
[`OSError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError) if the file does not exist or if you do not have the permission to access the file. For example:

```
try:
    if os.path.getsize(my_path) > 0:
        # Non empty file exists
        # ... your code ...
    else:
        # Empty file exists
        # ... your code ...
except OSError as e:
    # File does not exists or is non accessible
    # ... your code ...
```

---

**References** from the Python 3 document

- [**`os.path.getsize()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize) will:

  > Return the size, in bytes, of path. Raise [`OSError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError) if the file does not exist or is inaccessible.

  For empty file, it will return `0`. For example:

  ```
  >>> import os
  >>> os.path.getsize('README.md')
  0
  ```
- whereas [**`os.path.exists(path)`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) will:

  > Return `True` if path refers to an existing path or an open file descriptor. Returns `False` for broken symbolic links.
  >
  > On some platforms, this function may return `False` if permission is not granted to execute [`os.stat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat) on the requested file, even if the path physically exists.

Comment: I use this to check if I must download a file: `must_be_downloaded = not os.path.isfile(file_path) or os.path.getsize(file_path) == 0` and it works w/o try/catch in python 3.6. Or use the opposite: `exists_for_real = os.path.isfile(file_path) and os.path.getsize(file_path) > 0` you can make your own checked and add more conditions, but I just scripted the same and this simple check works well in my case.

Answer (score 6):

On Python3 you should use pathlib.Path features for this purpose:

```py
import pathlib as p
path = p.Path(f)
if path.exists() and path.stat().st_size > 0:
   raise RuntimeError("file exists and is not empty")
```

As you see the Path object contains all the functionality needed to perform the task.

Answer (score 2):

```
def exist_and_not_empty(filepath):
    try:
        import pathlib as p
        path = p.Path(filepath)
        if '~' in filepath:
            path = path.expanduser()
        if not path.exists() and path.stat().st_size > 0:
            return False
        return True
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return False
```

This leverages all of the suggestions above and accounts for missing files and autoexpands tilde if detected so it just works.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this:

```
def existandnotempty(fp):
    if not os.path.isfile(fp):
        retun False
    k=0
    with open(fp,'r') as f:
        for l in f:
          k+=len(l)
          if k:
             return False
          k+=1
    return True
```

Comment: You can modify this as please. For exmple, you can use ' trim() ' if you dont want tabs, spaces, etc to be counted as "something". You can also remove the k+=1 if want to count as "empty" a file with only empty lines. In this form, any character ( even just a CR) would flag your file as non-empty.